# RabbitMQ limited to one slave

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, rabbitmq

I am having an odd issue with rabbitmq when deploying on AWS.

When I spin up a master and connect a slave to it everything goes fine and I have two servers in the cluster. When I go to add the second slave to the master it just hangs on join_cluster and will wait indefinitely without throwing any errors. As soon as I stop the first slave the second will instantly join. I can't find anyone else with this issue or any setting that limits the number of slaves.

this is the steps I run on both slave servers after adding an entry to the host file that point an ip to master

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl reset
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@master
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

this is my rabbitmq.config file.

```
    [
 {rabbit,
  [
   {tcp_listeners, [{{ rabbitmq_amqp_port }}]},

   %% SSL listeners are configured in the same fashion as TCP listeners,
   %% including the option to control the choice of interface.
   %%
   %% {ssl_listeners, [5671]},

   %% Maximum time for AMQP 0-8/0-9/0-9-1 handshake (after socket connection
   %% and SSL handshake), in milliseconds.
   %%
   %% {handshake_timeout, 10000},

    {log_levels, [{connection, info}]},
    {loopback_users, [<<"{{ rabbitmq_loopback_user }}">>]},

   %% Configuring SSL.
   %% See http://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html for full documentation.
   %%
   %% {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,           "/path/to/testca/cacert.pem"},
   %%                {certfile,             "/path/to/server/cert.pem"},
   %%                {keyfile,              "/path/to/server/key.pem"},
   %%                {verify,               verify_peer},
   %%                {fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}]},
    {default_vhost,       <<"{{ rabbitmq_default_vhost }}">>},
    {default_user,        <<"{{ rabbitmq_default_user }}">>},
    {default_pass,        <<"{{ rabbitmq_default_pass }}">>},
    {default_permissions, [<<".*">>, <<".*">>, <<".*">>]},
    {default_user_tags, [{{ rabbitmq_default_user_tags }}]},
    {channel_max, 128},

   %% Customising Socket Options.
   %%
   %% See (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#setopts-2) for
   %% further documentation.
   %%
   %% {tcp_listen_options, [binary,
   %%                       {packet,        raw},
   %%                       {reuseaddr,     true},
   %%                       {backlog,       128},
   %%                       {nodelay,       true},
   %%                       {exit_on_close, false}]},

    {vm_memory_high_watermark, {{ rabbitmq_high_watermark }} },
    {vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio, {{ rabbitmq_high_watermark_paging }} },

   %% Set disk free limit (in bytes). Once free disk space reaches this
   %% lower bound, a disk alarm will be set - see the documentation
   %% listed above for more details.
   %%
   %% {disk_free_limit, 50000000},

      {disk_free_limit, {mem_relative, {{rabbitmq_disk_free_limit}} }}

   %% Make clustering happen *automatically* at startup - only applied
   %% to nodes that have just been reset or started for the first time.
   %% See http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#auto-config for
   %% further details.
   %%
   %% {cluster_nodes, {['rabbit@my.host.com'], disc}},
  ]}
].
```

full writeup availble on rabbitmq mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/Mzb2EhFUD0w